# How do I replace part of my json request body with the result of a java function/method in jmeter?

Tags: java, rest, api, jmeter

I'm new to jmeter. I'm using `Jmeter` for performance testing of my APIs. There I have a sample request which has a key1 and a dummy value as part of the HTTP request. The complete Json request is generated dynamically each time based on output of a previous `Rest API` call. I have to run my `java` method on the dynamic `HTTP Request`.  Once I run the `java` method, the value of the key1 part of the `Http` request has to be replaced by the value returned by the `java` function/method.

Sample Dynamic Http Request :-

```
{
  "ver": "1.0",
  "timestamp":"2019-08-28T11:39:57.153Z",
  "Details": {
        "key": "Previous API call value",
        "key": "Previous API call value"
      }
    ],
  "key1": "Dummy Value"
}
```

The dummy value has to be replaced with the output returned by the java function. I'm able to fetch the `Previous API call value` using Regular Expression Extractor. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inline [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) directly into your HTTP request body and place your `java` code inside the function

Example:

```
{
  "ver": "1.0",
  "timestamp":"2019-08-28T11:39:57.153Z",
  "Details": {
        "key": "Previous API call value",
        "key": "Previous API call value"
      }
    ],
  "key1": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10),)}"
}
```

Demo:

[image]

In the above example [RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#randomAlphanumeric-int-) function is executed, however you can put arbitrary java/groovy code there, it will be executed in the runtime and the placeholder will be substituted with the function output.

- [Apache Groovy: Documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Can you give a small example of java code inside __groovy. It would be really helpful. I'm not able to run the java code inside the __groovy function